# Div on top of nav with overlapping clickable logo

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble wrapping my around this problem:

I want to have a header consisting of a "top-bar" with a brand-logo in the middle and maybe some important links to the left and right of it.
The logo should be clickable and is bigger (in height) than the top-bar itself, which means it should overlap with the navigation below. The problem now is, that the logo is indeed overlapping, but also blocking the links below with it's own link. The clickeable part of the logo should only be as heigh as the height of the "top-bar".

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<header role="banner">
    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="logo-brand">
        <a href="/test">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pKkt4bq.png" alt="Welcome" id="logo">
            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default ng-scope" role="navigation" ng-controller="navbarCtrl">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div uib-collapse="isCollapsed" class="navbar-collapse bs-js-navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Load</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Save</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Assign</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

**CSS:**

```
header .top-bar {
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 100;
  background: url('../../data/images/top-links.jpg') repeat-x;
}

header .top-bar .logo-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 429px;
  z-index: 2;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

And here is a fiddle to see the problem in action. Notice how the right-most links are not clickable, because they are beneath the logo?
http://jsfiddle.net/7mLtc3q1/

What are my options? I want this to be as mobile-friendly as possible.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: z-index won't work without relatively or absolutely positioning the element, so add either `position: relative` or `position: absolute` on your `header .top-bar` selector.

Comment: This does not fix the non-clickable area below the logo. As i said the link for the image should only be as heigh as the top-bar itself, and thus should not overlap onto the navigation bar. I updated the fiddle with your suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/7mLtc3q1/1/

Still thanks for that!

Comment: I'm sorry to say that but after checking the image provided in the fiddle... the image is too high. It will always overlap the navbar below.

A possible solution is to set an absolute height on the `.top-bar` container (you already got that with the 48px), which is **lower** than what the image overlaps and add `overflow: visible` but I can't guarantee that will fix the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `pointer-events:none` to your `.logo-brand` class:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7mLtc3q1/3/)**

Comment: This is probably the best solution, though worth adding is that it only works from IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple concept of how you could get around your issue.

As the logo-brand/image is a "square", its lower left/right corners will cover the nav bar, unless you put it beneath the nav bar.

Put it beneath will cause issues if the nav bar has a background color or image, but would "cut of" the clickable logo where the nav bar starts.

The below snippet show by setting the logo/image border bottom rounded, make the left/right bottom part of the nav bar "uncovered".

As you can see, the red rounded only react when you hover in it, not where its "right/left bottom corner" would normally be if not rounded.

Another way, not shown here, would be to cut the logo in 2 and put the lower part as a background in your nav bar, though this would slightly more complexed.

```css
header .top-bar {
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .top-bar div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color: red;
  width: 240px;
  border-radius: 50% / 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

header .top-bar div:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

header .navbar {
   background-color: lightgray;
   height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
    <div class="top-bar">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default ng-scope" role="navigation">
    </nav>
</header>
```